# AngularJS & Entity Framework - Creating association without duplicating entity

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity

I am using Angular and EF, and I am trying to create an association on the client side, send this to the server, and have the database updated.

I have 2 entities, EQUIPMENT and INCIDENT. EQUIPMENT has an association with INCIDENT.

Here is some code:

```
//Returns an INCIDENT EF entity from db
    var incpromise = NewIncidentService.getRecordFromID(1);


    incpromise.then(function(pl) {

        var New4312 = {
            SNumber: $scope.SNumber,               
            INCIDENT: pl.data //SET THE ASSOCIATION
        };

   .......
   New4312Service.post(New4312);
.....

  New4312Service.post = function (New4312) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/api/Equipment/PostEQUIPMENT",
        data: New4312
    });
    return request;
};
```

And here is the web api method on the server:

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(EQUIPMENT))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostEQUIPMENT(EQUIPMENT eQUIPMENT)
    {
       /* if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }*/

        db.EQUIPMENTs.Add(eQUIPMENT);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
```

The problem I am having is every time I run this, EF is duplicating the incident object in the database. How can I make it so I just set the association between My EQUIPMENT entity and INCIDENT entity without it duplciating everytime I create a new EQUIPMENT entity? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by making sure to set the state of my entity.

```
 _uow.UOWContext.Entry(eq).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

The state of the entity that was getting posted was "Detached", so I set it to modified instead and it works perfectly.